# Syntax error, unexpected end-of-file

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, unexpectendoffile

I have a script that is throwing this error.

This usually means there is a loop (like an `if` or `do`) that is not correctly ended, or there are too many `end` clauses. I can't find the issue. Any good tips on how to identify this kind of syntax error?

It could also be a double-quote issue. Wondering if there is a way (in ultra-edit or text editor) to detect lines of script that have un-even numbers of double quotes.

Comment: Well, the first tip is to post your code. You will get zero help troubleshooting a piece of code no one can see.

Comment: Comment out some lines so that the code runs, start removing commented lines until it breaks. If you still can't find it, post your code.

Comment: If you use good indentation, it's usually fairly easy to look up and down and make sure all of your loops have and `end`

Comment: Or use a good code editor, it will flag many problems for you.

Comment: I do use proper indentation and I use ultra edit.  My eyes just couldn't see the issue lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind, I found the issue.  I commented out the newest definition that I had added and it ran.  That let me know it was that definition.  I then took that out and went through it with a darn comb.  Found that I was checking a value, but hadn't allowed for it to be nil or empty.  Added that in and now I'm good.

Comment: Forgetting to check a case in a conditional is a semantic error and cannot possibly introduce a `SyntaxError`, so including that case cannot possibly fix it, or at least only accidentally.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to: "It could also be a double-quote issue, possibly. Wondering if there is a way to detect any lines of script (in ultra-edit or text editor) where there are an un-even number of double quotes."

[Sublime is a great editor that is available for most platforms.](http://www.sublimetext.com)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, comment out blocks of code using `=begin` ... `=end` and/or `# ...` and narrow down the error.

For the second question, use syntax highlighting on the text editor. You can easily tell how long a single string literal is continued, and find unbalanced quotes.